Как изменить позицию div content в слайдере
Всем привет я новичок в верстке и вот с какой проблемой я столкнулся:
код html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="box" style="background-image: url('./img/biology.jpg')">
        <div class="content">
          <h2 class="title">"The Migration"</h2>
          <p class="description">
            В этом разделе предлагаем обсудить различные математические задачи и
            проблемы, составленные Вами и не обязательно Вами, для которых Вы
            имеете решения. Обсуждение задач по математике, предлагавшихся на
            школьных и студенческих олимпиадах: региональных, национальных,
            международных. Обсуждение нетривиальных и нестандартных учебных
            задач Дискуссионные темы математики: попытки доказательства ВТФ и
            т.п.
          </p>
          <button>Read More</button>
        </div></div>
      <div class="box" style="background-image: url('./img/chess.jpg')">
        <div class="content">
          <h2 class="title">"The Migration"</h2>
          <p class="description">
            В этом разделе предлагаем обсудить различные математические задачи и
            проблемы, составленные Вами и не обязательно Вами, для которых Вы
            имеете решения. Обсуждение задач по математике, предлагавшихся на
            школьных и студенческих олимпиадах: региональных, национальных,
            международных. Обсуждение нетривиальных и нестандартных учебных
            задач Дискуссионные темы математики: попытки доказательства ВТФ и
            т.п.
          </p>
          <button>Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box" style="background-image: url('./img/history.jpg')">
        <div class="content">
          <h2 class="title">"The Migration"</h2>
          <p class="description">
            В этом разделе предлагаем обсудить различные математические задачи и
            проблемы, составленные Вами и не обязательно Вами, для которых Вы
            имеете решения. Обсуждение задач по математике, предлагавшихся на
            школьных и студенческих олимпиадах: региональных, национальных,
            международных. Обсуждение нетривиальных и нестандартных учебных
            задач Дискуссионные темы математики: попытки доказательства ВТФ и
            т.п.
          </p>
          <button>Read More</button>
        </div></div>
      <div class="box" style="background-image: url('./img/math.jpg')">
        <div class="content">
          <h2 class="title">"The Migration"</h2>
          <p class="description">
            В этом разделе предлагаем обсудить различные математические задачи и
            проблемы, составленные Вами и не обязательно Вами, для которых Вы
            имеете решения. Обсуждение задач по математике, предлагавшихся на
            школьных и студенческих олимпиадах: региональных, национальных,
            международных. Обсуждение нетривиальных и нестандартных учебных
            задач Дискуссионные темы математики: попытки доказательства ВТФ и
            т.п.
          </p>
          <button>Read More</button>
        </div></div>
    </div>

код css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.box {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  transition: 800ms ease-in-out;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.box:first-of-type {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-10deg);
}
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 20%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-10deg) translateZ(-50px);
}
.box:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 25%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-10deg) translateZ(-100px);
}
.box:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-10deg) translateZ(-150px);
}
.box:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 35%;
  opacity: 0.25;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-10deg) translateZ(-200px);
}
.box:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 40%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-10deg) translateZ(-250px);
}

.content {
  width: min(30vw, 400px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font: 400 0.85rem helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   /* opacity: 0;
  display: block; */
}
.content .title {
  font-family: "arial-black";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.content .description {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin: 1rem 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.content button {
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2) .content {
  display: block;
  animation: show 0.75s ease-in-out 0.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateY(calc(-50% + 75px));
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}


код js
    const box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
box.forEach((elemBox) => {
  elemBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
    elemBox.remove();
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    container.appendChild(elemBox);
  });
});

При нажатии на картинку я хочу что бы .content появлялся слева от картинки то есть не в самой картинке а вообще как отдельный элемент. Прикрепил скрин 
Я знаю что нужно создать контент отдельно от img но тогда у меня летит слайдер. Как мне это сделать? Заранее благодарю
